# Concate first and previous records with SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica

I have a file from which I need to insert data into table that looks like this:

[image]

I need to concatenate every record that starts with DTL with the record that starts with DT2 behind it.

In Informatica that soultion looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The file is loaded like one column only.

Comment: Does your data have some sort of sequence field to it, because once you load into Snowflake, there is no order of records maintained.  So, if you are asking how to do this in SQL, but there is no record identifier, then you won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For previous row result, LAG can also be used -

```
with data_cte as 
(SELECT column1 from values
 ('ABCfs'),
 ('DT2ad'),
 ('DTLskf'),
 ('DT2etv'),
 ('DTLbrf'),
 ('DT2tf'),
 ('ABCbr'),
 ('DT2g6'),
 ('DTLdh'),
 ('DT2jw')
 ), c_p_cte as
 (
 select substr(column1,1,3) column1,lag(substr(column1,1,3)) 
over (order by null) column2 from data_cte 
 )
 select case 
 when column1='DTL' and column2='DT2' then column1||column2
 else column1
 end col_val
 from c_p_cte;
```

With above query, it results as -

```
COL_VAL
-------
ABC
DT2
DTLDT2
DT2
DTLDT2
DT2
ABC
DT2
DTLDT2
DT2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
with 
t_rownum as 
(SELECT data_string,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
FROM TEMP_TABLE),
t_dtl as (select * from t_rownum where SUBSTRING(DATA_STRING,1,3)='DTL'),
t_dt2 as (select * from t_rownum where SUBSTRING(DATA_STRING,1,3)='DT2'),
t_dtl_2 as (select 
t_dtl.data_string || t_dt2.data_string as data_string
from t_dtl inner join t_dt2 on t_dtl.rownum=t_dt2.rownum-1)
SELECT
DATA_STRING
FROM t_dtl_2 WHERE SUBSTRING(DATA_STRING,1,3)='DTL'
and SUBSTRING(DATA_STRING,255,3)='DT2'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole row of data seems to be read into one `RECORD_DETAIL` port (think of that as a column). Hence, this single port is loaded into single column in your target DB.

In order to have separate columns loaded, you need to read the file as a delimited one. In this case using pipe (`|`) as the delimiter.

Now, you mention you need to "concatenate every record that" - to my understanding this would mean concatenating all columns of all rows. And this is exactly what happens there.